How exactly is Empirical KL Divergence Defined and how is it calculated
Suppose that we have two independent identically distributed samples. The first sample looks like $x_1 , \ldots, x_n$ with $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for every $i$. The second sample looks like $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ with $y_j \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for every $j$.
How is the empirical KL divergence between them defined? Put $P$ to be the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ whose cumulative distribution function is the empirical cumulative distribution function of the first sample and $Q$ similarly for the second sample. Is the empirical KL divergence just the KL divergence between $P$ and $Q$?
If this is indeed the case, is there any reference on how I can compute this quantity knowing the values of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ and $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ ?

This question is not well posed. You may benefit from having a peek on our tutorial paper for the meaning of the KL divergence: https://www.mdpi.com/2673-9984/5/1/22

It’s $ P_nKL$ where the estimand is  $PKL$, where $KL=logQ/P$ - see van der Vaart’s asymptotics text for the $P_n,P$ notation. Note $P=E$. Empirical KL is $1/n\sum_i log Q(x_i)/P(x_i)$ for example. I don’t think you need the $y_1,…,y_n$

I do not understand your answer. The point of KL divergence is to compare two distributions. How can we do it without another sample ?

it is to compare two distribution functions

No. It compares two probability measures and not necessarily density functions.
